# Is there an Azure DevOps Rest API to fetch Organization name change details

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

Suppose if Organization name was changed in Azure DevOps.
Is there an Azure DevOps Rest API to fetch Organization name change details if I have the old Organization name.

Admin renamed Organization in Azure DevOps.
Need to programmatically fetch Organization name change details through Azure DevOps Rest API using the old Organization name.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, after renaming an organization, the old name will be replaced with new name in the database. When trying to use Azure DevOps REST API to query any details of the organization, you need to use the latest organization name. So, it is not possible to use the old organization name to run the REST API.

To get the name change details, you can try using the REST API for [**Audit Log**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/audit/audit-log?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1) with the new organization name.

1. Ensure the organization has connected to Azure AD so that you can use the **Audit Log** feature.

   [image]
2. Ensure the option "**Log Audit Events**" has been enabled before renaming the organization.

   [image]
3. If above prerequisites are met, then you can view the name change details from Auditing logs in Azure DevOps or using the REST API for **Audit Log**.

   [image]

When using the REST API for **Audit Log**, you also can use the parameters **`startTime`** and **`endTime`** to filter the logs based on the datetime (**UTC**) of the name change event.

```
GET https://auditservice.dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/audit/auditlog?startTime={startTime}&endTime={endTime}&api-version=7.1-preview.1
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Ran, 
Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: Hi @Ashish, You're welcome. Please have a try with it if you think it is helpful for you.